# Рисование линии с изменяющимся цветом

Tags: android, opengl

1. `OpenGL ES 2.0` как нарисовать линию? 2D то есть просто абстрактная линия.
2. Что значит задание координат в `x,xf` что такое `f` - это приведение к float?
3. Можно ли у линии изменять цвет в рантайме?

Answer (score 1):

На первый вопрос читайте "OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide"(только на английском).

На второй "OpenGL red book"(есть и на русском) по секрету суффикс f обозначает число с плавающей точкой 32 бита.

Третье да естественно можно так как OpenGL достаточно низкоуровневая спецификация, вы ограничены только собственно фантазией.

P.S. Книги читать обязательно OpenGL полон слегка не очевидных подходов.